# PHP mixing up sessions

Tags: php, session, caching

I've been having problems with sessions for some days now in my production environment

I've already tried to find the solution in tons and tons of answers here in stack overflow, but none seem to work for me

1. User A logs in
2. User B logs in. Now when you go back to User A
   his session was overwritten by User B. So I have two users 'sharing' the
   same session.

Side notes:

1. I have session_start() on the very top of every page using session variables
2. I'm using https with a valid certificate
3. Cache is not the problem, I've already tried to set headers to avoid caching

I'm using PHP 5.4 (I was using 5.6 before and downgraded hoping it would solve my problem) and this is my PHP.ini:

> session.save_path = "/tmp"
>
> session.cookie_secure = 1
>
> session.use_cookies = 1
>
> session.use_only_cookies = 1
>
> session.name = PHPSESSID
>
> session.entropy_length = 32
>
> session.cache_limiter = nocache
>
> session.cache_expire = 180
>
> session.hash_function = sha256

And this is the basic structure of my authentication page:

```
session_start();
... // after connection with the database I retrieve id and name
$_SESSION['id_logado'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['nome_logado'] = $user_name;
```

I've already double checked every line of code in every page. There is no variable name $id_logado so it should not interfere with that. Cache is *probably* not the problem because I have headers to avoid caching just after session_start. I've contacted bluehost to ask for help and of course they have no idea and are blaming myself.

Comment: Your description of what you perceive to be a problem is not accurate. When user B logs in his information replaces user As information. They are not "sharing" anything. What do you expect to happen differently when user B logs in? If you believe there is really a problem please show us the code in question.

Comment: Only 1 user should login each session or is my logic wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain why you think there is a `singleton` session as it where ? How have you come to this conclusion that User A's session is being replaced ?

Comment: Hi Dave, I expect User B to have his user ID saved in his session, but not change User A's session. When User B logs in now User A's session is being updated to User B's ID. I understand that sessions are meant to be unique for each user and not global for everyone

Comment: @Pogrindis Because User A is using the system just fine, but when someone else login from another computer, he suddenly becomes User B. I had some huge security problems because random users are having access to admin accounts

Comment: I would look into `session_id()` then for debugging.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php But it sounds suspicious.. Would need to see more.

Comment: @Pogrindis This doesn't happen everytime. Yesterday we had one new user that was changing session values with one of our admins. But just this one specific case. I had contact with both of them and did several tests. And for them it happens all the time. But my session was not mixed with any of them. They were just having mixed sessions between them two. Since this is not that common, I suspect for some reason sessions are being assigned the same id in some specific conditions, but I know this is extremely unlikely to happen

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

After further investation I noticed that the /tmp folder had only one session file, with a big size. For some reason sessions were not being saved to new files and were being 'added' to the same one.

Solution: I've created a new folder inside my home drive and granted 777 permissions. Updated my php.ini file to use that folder instead of /tmp and now I have tons of sessions being properly generated.